# Import/Use XrmServiceToolkit on Microsoft CRM 2013

Tags: crm

how I use XrmServiceToolkit? Where I import this solution on Microsoft CRM 2013?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you. This is having all information related to xrmservicetoolkit.

https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/

http://sumedha8.blogspot.in/2014/03/rest-functions-from-xrmservicetoolkit.html

Add the libraryto your CRM form:

[image]

Sample code to use the library:

```
function Retrieve() {
    var re;
    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Retrieve(
              "{EE81D2A9-E28E-E311-96DF-D89D6765B238}",
              "AccountSet",
              null, null,
              function (result) {
                  re = result;
                  alert("success");
              },
              function (error) {
                  alert("failed");
              },
              false
          );
    //debugger;
    alert(re.Name);
    alert(re.AccountId);
}

function Delete() {
    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Delete(
                "{32815A55-19AF-E311-BF0E-D89D6765B238}",
                "AccountSet",
                function () {
                    alert("successfully deleted");
                },
                function (error) {
                    alert("failed to delete");
                },
                false
            );
}

function Update() {

    var account = {};
    account.Name = "SO and Company A1";
    account.Address1_AddressTypeCode = { Value: 3 }; //Address 1: Address Type = Primary
    account.Address1_City = "Wentworthville";
    account.Address1_Line1 = "153 Dunmore Stret";

    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Update(
        "{EE81D2A9-E28E-E311-96DF-D89D6765B238}",
        account,
        "AccountSet",
        function () {
            alert("successfully Updated");
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("failed to Update");
        },
        false
    )

}

function Create() {
    var account = {};
    account.Name = "SO and Company B1";
    account.Address1_AddressTypeCode = { Value: 3 }; //Address 1: Address Type = Primary
    account.Address1_City = "Wentworthville B";
    account.Address1_Line1 = "153 Dunmore Stret B";

    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create(
                    account,
                    "AccountSet",
                    function (result) {
                        accountId = result.AccountId;
                        alert("successfully Created. Acc ID : " + result.AccountId);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("failed to Create Account");
                    },
                    false
    );

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Racil and agree to your point. Will do that in future.

Comment: Please update your answer, you can edit it and start right now instead of the future.